# Continuous and until

Tags: grammar, tense

Is it possible to use Continuous tenses together with 'until'? For example

> I will be working until 8 a.m.

In my opinion, Continuous sounds pretty logical since we're emphasizing duration, but I've met only Simple tenses in every book or article I've read so far.

EDIT:
I've found this example:

> I won't be seeing Judy until/before Tuesday.

Can I use 'I won't see Judy until Tuesday' and what's the difference?

Comment: They are fine as they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both sound valid according to my dialect of American English. My instinct tells me that 'I won't see Judy' implies that I simply do not have plans to see her until Thursday but could still run into her before then. 'I won't be seeing' implies that I'm certain I won't see her until then. So I think your instinct is correct: using continuous tense only emphasizes the certainty of the continuous action. 
However, in casual conversation you could use either form, it probably wouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can you continuous tense with until. The first sentence is fine

As for he second sentence , I prefer the present tense *see* instead of *be seeing*. The use of the present tense with the verb *to see* is more natural in my opinion.

Comment: I've found 'won't be seeing' in Michaels Swan's Practical English Usage. Honestly, I don't know which tense is better since Michael's book seems reliable, but you prefer to use 'see'. Maybe someone else can give his opinion.

Comment: I think your "preference" for simple present instead of present continuous is totally irrelevant. Both are perfectly natural usages, and it's unhelpful to suggest to non-native speakers that they should avoid the continuous form as a general principle.